# jQuery não enxerga conteúdo carregado via ajax

Tags: jquery

Como posso fazer com que os elementos carregados no layout sejam enxergados pelo jQuery?

Por exemplo: numa página pai tenho um script carregado junto com a página. Nessa página pai, tenho uma `DIV` com `ID="filho"`. Quando, num botão da página pai é clicado, carrego o resultado nessa DIV "filho". Porém, se eu quiser acessar algum elemento que acabara de ser carregado através do jQuery que já está carregado na página, não funciona. É como se não existisse. Como resolver isso?

Comment: Pode colocar aqui o seu código? Acho que o problema é delegação. Deve usar `$(pai).on('click' ,'filho', function(){ ...`

Comment: Eu entendi o link que postou antes. Mas, e quando o evento não é disparado via click? Exemplo: $(document).ready(function(){ carrega uma página via load ou ajax ...});

Comment: O melhor é colocar um exemplo concreto de código. Sem ver pode ser muita coisa...

Comment: A sua explicação está muito confusa, tente colocar parte do código para melhor visualização do problema e explique em tópicos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar uma função que será chamada assim que a pagina for carregada (callback)

Por exemplo:

```
$('div').load('http://pagina',function(){ /* Codigo da função quando o conteúdo existir */ })
```

Caso o HTML que esteja sendo carregado seja dinamico e possua eventos, vc deverá usar um evento delegate.

Por ex: (repare que neste exemplo construção o elemento #div1 deverá existir antes de carregar o conteudo e o botao #btAcao faz parte do HTML que será carregado)

```
$('#div1').on('click','#btAcao',function(){ 
    /* codigo do clique aqui */
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa utilizar o [método LIVE](https://api.jquery.com/live/) caso jQuery < 1.7 e o [método ON](https://api.jquery.com/on/) caso jQuery > 1.7.

Quando o DOM é carregado se o elemento não existe, mesmo que haja um evento para ele, ele não vai ser "Ligado" a esse evento quando passar a existir a menos que você utilize o método `on`. É uma boa prática você utilizar sempre o `on` ao invés de `click`.

Então troque

```
$('selector').click(function(){
   //ação para o click
});
```

por

```
$('selector').on('click',function(){
   //ação para o click
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Estava com o mesmo problema e o que funcionou foi utilizar o `.live()`:

```
$('#div1').live('click','#btAcao',function(){ 

})
```

[Documentação](https://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma

```
$("#meudiv").on("click", ".minhaclasse", function(){
   // Aqui pego o valor do objeto clicado, no caso minha classe
   var valor = $(this).val();
   alert(valor);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Cara, nesse artigo fala como resolver.
[link](https://www.williamzimmermann.com.br/2015/05/27/jquery-nao-reconhece-classes-adicionadas-a-pagina-dinamicamente/).

Ficaria assim:

```
$(document).on('click','.added_element',function() {
    console.log("FUNCIONA");    
});
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).